# Replicate a SQL Join + Group By in data.table

Tags: sql, r, data.table

I am trying to replicate a SQL sparse matrix multiplication using data tables. The SQL expression would be:

```
SELECT a.i, b.j, SUM(a.value*b.value)
FROM a, b
WHERE a.j = b.i
GROUP BY a.i, b.j;
```

where my data is structured as |i|j|value in each table

To create this data in R you can use:

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

A <- matrix(runif(25),5,5)
B <- matrix(runif(25),5,5)

ADT <- data.table(melt(A))
BDT <- data.table(melt(B))

setnames(ADT,old = c("Var1","Var2","value"), new = c("Ai","Aj","AVal"))
setnames(BDT,old = c("Var1","Var2","value"), new = c("Bi","Bj","BVal"))
```

To merge using .[ we need to set the keys that we join on:

```
setkey(ADT,"Aj")
setkey(BDT,"Bi")
```

To build up piece by piece

```
ADT[BDT, allow.cartesian = T]

     Ai Aj       AVal Bj      BVal
  1:  1  1 0.39230905  1 0.7083956
  2:  2  1 0.89523490  1 0.7083956
  3:  3  1 0.92464689  1 0.7083956
  4:  4  1 0.15127499  1 0.7083956
  5:  5  1 0.88838458  1 0.7083956
 ---                              
121:  1  5 0.70144360  5 0.7924433
122:  2  5 0.50409075  5 0.7924433
123:  3  5 0.15693879  5 0.7924433
124:  4  5 0.09164371  5 0.7924433
125:  5  5 0.63787487  5 0.7924433
```

So far so good. The merge worked properly, `Bi` has disappeared, but this is encoded by `Aj` anyway. We now want to multiply AVal by BVal, and then sum the created groups (! in the same expression, I know that I could store and apply a second expression here). I had thought this would be:

```
ADT[BDT, j = list(Ai, Bj, Value = sum(AVal*BVal)), by = c("Ai","Bj") , allow.cartesian = T]
```

but I get the error: `Object Bj not found`. In fact, none of the values from 'BDT' are usable once I insert the `by =` clause (try to systematically remove `Bj`,`BVal` and `"Bj"` from the expression above, left to right, and you will see what I mean).

Looking into the `.EACHI` expression, it seems like the motive is here to do what I want, but `.EACHI` groups on the merged index, not on a separate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you simply want to aggregate after the merge:

```
ADT[BDT, allow.cartesian = T][, sum(AVal * BVal), by = .(Ai, Bj)]
```

Comment: this depends on how DT interprets it. I could be wrong, but the above is the same as writing out two expressions, the first of `ADT[BDT, allow.cartesian = T]`, followed by the aggregate. It looks nice, and is on one line, but I would rather pass the entire expression through .[ so that it gets optimized in the back end as one complete expression.

Comment: @Chris yes it's two expressions one after another. I don't think you can do it during the join, and I don't see what kind of optimization you want tbh. You can add an example dataset where you run into speed issues that would help people consider benchmarks.

Comment: looks like FR for aggregation while cartesian join on different `by` then merge key, not sure.